# How do you prevent WordPress from wrapping images in <p> tags

Tags: wordpress

WordPress's wpautop function/formatting always adds `<p></p>` tags to images. Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: are you using line breaks before the image is used? 2= <p>

Comment: No, just inserting the image. I was just looking for a way to globally remove the <p></p> tags from images without having to wrap the image in <div></div> tags.

Answer (score 0):

I know you can wrap the image in div tags:

```
<div><img src='example_image.jpg' alt='example' /></div>
```

and this solves the problem on an image by image bases, but it would be useful to know if there is a way to do it globally via the functions.php.